# Cannot reinitialize with different application context

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, mule

I am using Mule with Spring Integration to implement sending SMS function , below is spring xml configuration :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<mule xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation"
    xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" version="EE-3.7.2"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:int="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration"
    xmlns:oxm="http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm" xmlns:int-http="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/http"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-current.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/http http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/http/spring-integration-http.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/spring-integration.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm/spring-oxm.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-current.xsd">
<spring:beans>

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.scholes.sf.message" />

    <oxm:jaxb2-marshaller id="sfRequestMarshaller">
        <oxm:class-to-be-bound name="com.scholes.sf.message.bean.SFSendSMSRequest" />
        <oxm:class-to-be-bound name="com.scholes.sf.message.bean.SFVerifySMSRequest" />
    </oxm:jaxb2-marshaller>

    <!-- send SMS -->
    <int:channel id="sendOobSmsResponseJsonChannel" />

    <int:channel id="sendOobSmsResponseObjectChannelOOB" />

    <int:channel id="sendOobSmsResponseObjectChannelSF" />

    <int:channel id="sendOobSmsRequestChannel" />

    <int:channel id="sendOobSmsResponseXmlChannel" />
    <int:channel id="verifyOobSmsResponseXmlChannel" />

    <int:channel id="verifyOobSmsRequestChannel" />

    <int:channel id="verifyOobSmsResponseObjectChannelSF" />

    <int:channel id="verifyOobSmsResponseObjectChannelOOB" />

    <int:channel id="verifyOobSmsResponseJsonChannel" />

    <int:object-to-json-transformer
        input-channel="sendOobSmsResponseObjectChannelOOB" output-channel="sendOobSmsResponseJsonChannel">
    </int:object-to-json-transformer>

    <int:transformer input-channel="sendOobSmsResponseObjectChannelSF"
        output-channel="sendOobSmsResponseObjectChannelOOB" ref="oobSendSMSTransformer" />

    <int:transformer input-channel="sendOobSmsResponseXmlChannel"
        output-channel="sendOobSmsResponseObjectChannelSF" ref="sfSendResponseUnmarshaller" />

    <int:transformer input-channel="sendOobSmsRequestChannel"
        output-channel="sendOobSmsResponseXmlChannel" ref="sfSendSmsTransformer" />
    <spring:bean id="sfSendSmsTransformer" class="com.scholes.sf.message.transformer.SFSendSMSTransformer" />

    <int:channel id="sendOobSmsResponseObjectChannel" />

    <spring:bean id="sfSendResponseUnmarshaller"
        class="org.springframework.integration.xml.transformer.UnmarshallingTransformer">
        <spring:constructor-arg>
            <oxm:jaxb2-marshaller id="sfSendRequestMarshaller">
                <oxm:class-to-be-bound name="com.scholes.sf.message.bean.SFSendSMSResponse" />
            </oxm:jaxb2-marshaller>
        </spring:constructor-arg>
    </spring:bean>

    <spring:bean id="oobSendSMSTransformer" class="com.scholes.sf.message.transformer.OOBSendSMSTransformer" /> 

    <!-- verify SMS -->
    <int:transformer input-channel="verifyOobSmsRequestChannel"
        output-channel="verifyOobSmsResponseXmlChannel" ref="sfVerifySmsTransformer" />
    <spring:bean id="sfVerifySmsTransformer" class="com.scholes.sf.message.transformer.SFVerifySMSTransformer" />

    <int:channel id="verifyOobSmsResponseObjectChannel" />

    <spring:bean id="sfVerifyResponseUnmarshaller"
        class="org.springframework.integration.xml.transformer.UnmarshallingTransformer">
        <spring:constructor-arg>
            <oxm:jaxb2-marshaller id="sfVerifyRequestMarshaller">
                <oxm:class-to-be-bound name="com.scholes.sf.message.bean.SFVerifySMSResponse" />
            </oxm:jaxb2-marshaller>
        </spring:constructor-arg>
    </spring:bean>

    <int:transformer input-channel="verifyOobSmsResponseXmlChannel"
        output-channel="verifyOobSmsResponseObjectChannelSF" ref="sfVerifyResponseUnmarshaller" />

    <int:transformer input-channel="verifyOobSmsResponseObjectChannelSF"
        output-channel="verifyOobSmsResponseObjectChannelOOB" ref="oobVerifySMSTransformer" />
    <spring:bean id="oobVerifySMSTransformer" class="com.scholes.sf.message.transformer.OOBVerifySMSTransformer" />

    <int:object-to-json-transformer
        input-channel="verifyOobSmsResponseObjectChannelOOB" output-channel="verifyOobSmsResponseJsonChannel">
    </int:object-to-json-transformer>

    <context:property-placeholder location="sms/oob-config.properties"/>



    </spring:beans>
</mule>
```

It seems try to initialize a second spring-integration context , so getting below error:

> WARN  2016-03-22 17:21:37,388 [main] org.mule.config.spring.MuleArtifactContext: Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'integrationRequestMappingHandlerMapping': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Cannot reinitialize with different application context: current one is [org.mule.config.spring.MuleDomainContext@1825085: startup date [Tue Mar 22 17:21:29 CST 2016]; root of context hierarchy], passed-in one is [org.mule.config.spring.MuleArtifactContext@14f3da4: startup date [Tue Mar 22 17:21:33 CST 2016]; parent: org.mule.config.spring.MuleDomainContext@1825085]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:547) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:753) ~[mule-module-spring-config-3.7.2.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757) ~[spring-context-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480) ~[spring-context-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
>       at org.mule.config.spring.SpringRegistry.doInitialise(SpringRegistry.java:108) ~[mule-module-spring-config-3.7.2.jar:3.7.2]

Any masters can help analyze this issue ? If I don't include this xml , then will be fine . How to make SI and Spring work together ?

Answer (score 0):

So this is the root cause

```
Cannot reinitialize with different application context: current one is
[org.mule.config.spring.MuleDomainContext@1825085: 
startup date [Tue Mar 22 17:21:29 CST 2016]; root of context hierarchy], 
passed-in one is [org.mule.config.spring.MuleArtifactContext@14f3da4: 
startup date [Tue Mar 22 17:21:33 CST 2016]; 
parent: org.mule.config.spring.MuleDomainContext@1825085] at 
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:547)
```

Check your XML namespaces. Maybe you just copy pasted it wrongly and then your context got clashed.

Also check your integrationRequestMappingHandlerMapping bean definition. It happens that it's initialized by different context. Please attach it's definition.

Answer (score 0):

That happened since you were mixing the mule spring config with SI which some of its components are not recognize. Can you try separating the SI config and then import it to mule config? Like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <mule xmlns=http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/c... ....>
     <spring:beans>
        <spring:import resource="si-config.xml" />
     </spring:beans>
```

Also, please check if you are using the correct version of Spring Integration by comparing the spring framework version used by EE 3.7.2 and SI you used.

Comment: Now I just programatically load the si-config.xml inside my java source to fix this issue.